# how to change precession format to % of pie chart using nvd3

Tags: nvd3.js

```
 
var barchart = nv.models.multiBarChart(); 

barchart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('%'));
```

like this  we can use for bar and line chart,
how to use this thing for  pie chart

Comment: Do you mind elaborating your question a bit more and what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

we can use this thing for % of pie

```
chart.valueFormat(d3.format('%'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still looking for an answer,[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860138/how-to-display-the-percentage-on-a-nvd3-pie-chart/16860855#16860855) is a simmilar question I answered.