# Tooltip NVD3 AreaStackChart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

How do I add sufix 'USD' depending on key type 'Spent', on tooltip as well as on yAxis?

And also I want the view should show only Impressions by default, but on click of other legend, suppose I click on Clicks or Installs or Spent, only the selected legend data should be visible on the graph.

Data:

```
[{"key":"Impressions","values":[[1405535400000,15132],[1405539000000,15216],[1405542600000,14385],[1405546200000,11291],[1405549800000,10798],[1405553400000,10460],[1405557000000,12787],[1405560600000,15948],[1405564200000,18891],[1405567800000,15536],[1405571400000,14793],[1405575000000,16771],[1405578600000,16441],[1405582200000,18943],[1405585800000,15560]]},{"key":"Clicks","values":[[1405535400000,137],[1405539000000,6],[1405542600000,13],[1405546200000,49],[1405549800000,33],[1405553400000,97],[1405557000000,50],[1405560600000,17],[1405564200000,181],[1405567800000,35],[1405571400000,107],[1405575000000,17],[1405578600000,7],[1405582200000,143],[1405585800000,96]]},{"key":"Installs","values":[[1405535400000,0],[1405539000000,0],[1405542600000,1],[1405546200000,3],[1405549800000,0],[1405553400000,7],[1405557000000,2],[1405560600000,0],[1405564200000,11],[1405567800000,2],[1405571400000,3],[1405575000000,1],[1405578600000,0],[1405582200000,9],[1405585800000,3]]},{"key":"Spent","values":[[1405535400000,0.01],[1405539000000,0.46],[1405542600000,0.22],[1405546200000,0.93],[1405549800000,0.17],[1405553400000,0.22],[1405557000000,0.8],[1405560600000,0.63],[1405564200000,0.34],[1405567800000,0.8],[1405571400000,0.07],[1405575000000,0.17],[1405578600000,0.43],[1405582200000,0.97],[1405585800000,0.19]]}]
```

Code:

```
function kMFormatter(num) {
if (num > 999) {
    if (num > 99999) {
        return d3.format(',.2f')(num / 100000) + ' M'
    }
    return d3.format(',.2f')(num / 1000) + ' K'
}
return num
}

function defaultChartConfig(container, data, useGuideline) {
    if (useGuideline === undefined) useGuideline = true;

if (typeof d3 !== 'undefined') {
    var colors = d3.scale.category20();
    keyColor = function (d, i) {
        return colors(d.key)
    };

    var chart;
    nv.addGraph(function () {
        chart = nv.models.stackedAreaChart()
            .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
            .x(function (d) {
                return d[0]
            })
            .y(function (d,key) {
                return d[1]
            })
            .color(keyColor)
            .transitionDuration(300)
            .showControls(false);



        chart.xAxis
            .tickFormat(function (d) {
                return d3.time.format('%X')(new Date(d))
            });

        chart.yAxis
            .tickFormat(function (d) {
                return kMFormatter(d);
            });


        d3.select('#' + container + ' svg')
            .datum(data)
            .transition().duration(1000)
            .call(chart)
            .each('start', function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    d3.selectAll('#d3_chart2 *').each(function () {
                        if (this.__transition__)
                            this.__transition__.duration = 1;
                    })
                }, 0)
            })

        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

        return chart;
    });


   }
}
```

Comment: To change the tooltip have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860138/how-to-display-the-percentage-on-a-nvd3-pie-chart?rq=1)

Comment: I could able to manipulate the core nvd3 library and got the tooltip functionality done. But I am not yet able to do the second functionality.

Comment: Could you put your code in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), so someone could have a look.

Comment: link to code http://jsfiddle.net/69AtH

Comment: The default behavior of NVD3 legends, when double clicking one,
is to set all other series to false, and make the double clicked series enabled. So only the selected legend data will be visible on the graph on dblclick event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've mentioned in my comment [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800375/tooltip-nvd3-areastackchart/24910752#comment38700987_24800375), the default behavior of NVD3 legends, when double clicking one, is to set all other series to false, and make the double clicked series enabled. So you'll need to override the legend's onclick event handler in order to make the second functionality work:

```
        d3.selectAll('.nv-series').on('click', function(d,i) {
           dispatch.legendDblclick(d,i);
           data.forEach(function(series) {
               series.disabled = true;
            });
           d.disabled = false;
           dispatch.stateChange({
              disabled: data.map(function(d) { return !!d.disabled })
           });
           chart.update();               
        })
```

Complete example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/W5QHL/2/)